# Errors with outputing strings/chars (C++)

Tags: c++

I had created a function called RNA_complement. It is supposed to take a line that was already read from the input file stream and replace the particular letters
with new letters (hence why it's called complement). After it's done, it's supposed to output the results to the output file stream (to the output file).

The problem is: it's not outputting the results to the file, even though i had written a command for it to do so. Why is it not going through?

the function was written outside of the int main function and the function was declared & initialized inside the main function.

I've gotten other errors such as "invalid conversion from char* to char" and "cannot convert string to char", etc. It's frustrating

here is the code:

```
char RNA_complement(string line)
{
char mychar[50];
ofstream genesacidnew;

  for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
  {
    line = mychar[i];
        if (mychar[i] == 'A')
        {
            mychar[i]= 'Z';

        }
    genesacidnew << "Complement: " <<mychar <<endl;
}

}
```

then i decided to initialize the function here

```
genesacid.open("genes.txt");
    if(!genesacid.is_open())
    {
        cerr <<"Error: File cannot be opened"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
        else
        {
            getline(genesacid, line1);

        }

genesacid.close();



genesacidnew.open("genesoutput.txt");
    if(!genesacidnew.is_open())
    {
        cerr <<"Error: File cannot be opened"<<endl;
        return -1;
    }
        else
        {
            genesacidnew<<"Fragment 1: " <<line1 <<endl;
            genesacidnew<<"Complement: "<<endl;
        }


RNA_complement(line1); /*here*/

genesacidnew.close();
```

Comment: When you get compile errors or warnings, there's a line number attached. Look in the appropriate file at the line and try to understand the error or warning and fix it of course.

Comment: That is **not** an RNA complement, even when correcting the obvious mistakes.

Comment: well I know... this is just a sample code. Of course I will write the real one once I get this to work. The real issue is getting the results to output to the output file

Comment: @user2188311 Ah, that actually makes sense. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

First off, let’s get clear on what an RNA complement is: it consists of replacing the letters of the RNA bases with the complementary base codes, i.e. `A` ↔ `U` and `C` ↔ `G` (I’m ignoring IUPAC ambiguity codes here since they’re rarely used).

Secondly, let’s specify the scope of your function. At the moment it (unsuccessfully) attempts to do two things:

1. Change the string itself, and
2. Write the changed bases to a file.

It also returns something (`char`) but it’s unclear what.

Let’s start from scratch and specify the semantics properly:

- The function `rna_complement` (note C++ naming conventions) takes an RNA fragment as a `std::string` (in all uppercase letters) and returns a complemented version of the fragment.

This is straightforward and unambiguous. **Now** we can implement it:

```
std::string rna_complement(std::string fragment) {
    for (unsigned pos = 0; pos < fragment.length(); ++pos) {
        switch (fragment[pos]) {
            case 'A': fragment[pos] = 'U'; break;
            case 'C': fragment[pos] = 'G'; break;
            case 'G': fragment[pos] = 'C'; break;
            case 'U': fragment[pos] = 'A'; break;
            default: assert(false); // This should never happen.
        }
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: okay how would you then output the results to the output file

Comment: @user2188311 If you want to output the whole changed text then yes, it would be `genesacidnew << line` in your code, or `genesacidnew << fragment` in mine, given that the stream is correctly initialised.

Comment: I had written this as a function outside of the "int main" function and i want to implement this function into the code. I'm not exactly sure if it should be added underneath the "ofstream" function but I had tried that but it's only outputting the complement.

Comment: i already had it outputting a line that was read straight from the input line. I also wanted to output the complement line underneath it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `RNA_complement` function you wrote:

```
ofstream genesacidnew;
```

You never specified which file to write to. Use like this

```
ofstream genesacidnew("Myfilename.ext");
```

Comment: okay i just fixed it but the characters on the output file came out weird. I dont know what has happened here..